# How can I jump to a activity by pressing the back button?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to help for this question on Android Studio.

How can I jump to an activity by pressing the back button? We don't add any button. Just clicking the back button on an android phone.

For example:

1. I am **going from activity1 to activity2**
2. I am **going from activity2 to activity3**
3. When I press the back button, I want to **jump to activity1**, not activity2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `onBackPressed` on the current activity, and in this `onBackPressed` you can jump back to any activity you want.

Example:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**The appropriate solution for your case:**
while going to `activity 3` from `activity 2`, you can call the `finish()` (after `startActivity` call) method, now when you press the back button on `activity 3`, you will be redirected back to `activity 1`.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

Comment: Thank you so much, my English not really good, so i didn't find anywhere.